# HTML/FPDF Table

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am working on printing this report to pdf:

[image: goodReport]

But all I get is this:

[image: badReport]

In this report, every student has a record in the columns `Exam`, `Progress Report`, `Quiz`, and `Project`.

Example Data:

[image]

Here is the part of my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_criteria)){
    $criteria[] = $row['criteria'];
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Cell(35,5,$row['criteria'],1,'','C');
}
    $pdf->Cell(35,5,'Grade',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(35,5,'Remark',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Ln();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $criteria_array = implode(" ", $criteria);
    $query_rec = mysql_query("SELECT equivalent FROM tb_student_record WHERE instructor_id = '$inst_id' AND criteria = '$criteria_array' AND description = '$desc' AND subj_code = '$code' AND term = '$term'");
    $record = mysql_fetch_array($query_rec);
    $name = $row['stud_name'];
    $course = $row['course_and_year'];
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Cell(1);
    $pdf->Cell(40,4,$name,1);
    $pdf->Cell(20,4,$course,1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(5,4,$record['equivalent'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

So if there is any or something wrong with it kindly... Please point it out guys.. Any help will appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: So you *have* the info, and you want to print it?  (In table form)

Comment: @cullub yes sir, I have, and I want to print it

Comment: You're only trying to output `$record['equivalent']` after the `$name` and `$course`, then you call out `$pdf->Ln();` already, so there are only total of three columns per row in your data. What do you want to show else?

Comment: Can you state the columns and give some sample data from your `tb_student_record`?

Comment: So the problem is that it's not printing the `Exam`, `Progress Report`, `Quiz`, and `Project` Columns?

Comment: I mean, what are the columns in your `tb_student_record` table? Besides `equivalent` column. Are the grades stored in that table?

Comment: @LoganWayne okay here sir http://i.imgur.com/f0bAFMR.png

Comment: @LoganWayne Can you `var_dump` `$row` inside your `while` loop, and give a few of the results?

Comment: I think your `tb_student_record` table only stores the `Exam`. Where do you store the `Progress Report`, `Quiz` and `Project scores`?

Comment: @LoganWayne actually sir I already added alot of records in my table so the other criteria is in next page of the phpmyadmin, I assure that Progress Report, Quiz and project is also stored in tb_student_record

Comment: So in your `criteria` column, you have `Exam`, `Progress Report`, `Quiz`, and `Project`? Those are the exact text? Can you update your provided code? Like what's the value of `$criteria_array`?

Comment: @LoganWayne yes sir It is the exact text, and the value of $criteria_array is : Exam Progress Report Quiz Project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php/fpdf table printing the same records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517583/php-fpdf-table-printing-the-same-records)

Answer (score 2):

- You only try to display three columns per row in your code
- We have to run through all the criteria to show the necessary data to display

Lets say `$criteria` is an array (remove the `implode()` part):

```
$criteria = array("Exam", "Progress Report", "Quiz", "Project");
```

Then run them all and bind it to your query:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9); /* SET FONT TO ARIAL WITH FONT SIZE OF 9 */

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ /* RUN THROUGH EACH STUDENT */

  $pdf->Cell(1);
  $pdf->Cell(40,4,$row['stud_name'],1); /* DISPLAY THE STUDENT'S NAME */
  $pdf->Cell(20,4,$row['course_and_year'],1,0,'C'); /* DISPLAY THE COURSE AND YEAR */

  for($x = 0; $x < count($criteria); $x++){ /* RUN ALL FOUR CRITERIAS */

    $query_rec = mysql_query("SELECT equivalent FROM tb_student_record WHERE instructor_id = '$inst_id' AND criteria = '".$criteria[$x]."' AND description = '$desc' AND subj_code = '$code' AND term = '$term'");
    $record = mysql_fetch_array($query_rec);
    $pdf->Cell(5,4,$record['equivalent'],1,0,'C'); /* DISPLAY THE SCORE FOR THE EQUIVALENT CRITERIA */

  } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

  $pdf->Ln(); /* NEW LINE */

} /* END OF WHILE LOOP; RUNNING THROUGH ALL THE STUDENTS */
```

And by the way, if you have time, consider using [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for your projects, rather than using the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*`.

Comment: hi sir your code serve as my basis and it help me with my problem but unfortunately all the records are the same so it is a another problem. And for clarification of the report I want to add 2 cells below the criteria which are(Ave and %) something like this -> http://i.imgur.com/WQTjoee.png btw this is my latest code -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRtxsi3HCNWSU5PNkhTekJPaVE/view I also started a new question for better explanation -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505173/fpdf-table-printing-the-same-result